# Comparing entries in dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, compare

I have 2 identical dataframes, we can use this as an example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'name': ['Sheldon', 'Penny', 'Amy', 'Penny', 'Raj', 'Sheldon'],
                'episodes': [42, 24, 31, 29, 37, 40],
                'gender': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male']}
data1 = {'name': ['Sheldon', 'Penny', 'Amy', 'Penny', 'Raj', 'Sheldon'],
                'episodes': [12, 32, 31, 32, 37, 40],
                'gender': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male']}    

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['name','episodes', 'gender'])    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name','episodes', 'gender'])
for names in df['name']:
    if (df[df['name'].str.contains(f'{names}')]['episodes']).any() == (df1[df1['name'].str.contains(f'{names}')]['episodes']).any():
        print('True')
        
    else:
        print('False')
```

It is checking if the number of episodes are different between the two dataframes and should print `false` where they are different episodes. But I am getting all `True`

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

Why is it not printing false?

Comment: What is your expected output when there are repetitive names, like `Sheldon`? Do you want it to compare just index-wise?

Comment: in your example , both df and df1 gets the dict `data` , none gets `data1`, could you please rectify the same?

Comment: The `any()` method returns a boolean type value and for your code, you always have a `True` value on both sides of the `==` operator. So, you are always getting `true` in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set_index` then compare `episodes` columns:

```
>>> df.set_index('name')['episodes'] == df1.set_index('name')['episodes']
name
Sheldon    False
Penny      False
Amy         True
Penny      False
Raj         True
Sheldon     True
Name: episodes, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Since `name` column includes duplicated values, I think this answer gives the same result as `.eq()` method, right?
For example,  for `Sheldon` in the first and last items, there are three values. and I guess after setting `name` column as the index, still it compares it in the order that they are for duplicated names.

Answer (score 2):

you can use **`.eq()`** method:

```
print(df.episodes.eq(df1.episodes))

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: episodes, dtype: bool
```

Comment: It worked only because `name` values are aligned between dataframes. Try: `df1.index += 10` then `df.episodes.eq(df1.episodes))`.

Comment: You're right. I asked OP in the comment if they expect a name-wise comparison or just a integer index comparison. I didn't get any answer, so I posted this.

Comment: @ashkangh I wanted name-wise but your solution was very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can just try `merge`

```
df.merge(df1,on='name',how='left').eval('episodes_x==episodes_y')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to put data1 into df1? Right now you have created df1 and df both from data alone. Also, you don't really need to go through it row by row. (df == df1)['episodes'] should give you what you want.